# No wi-fi adapter found - Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: wireless

Not sure what happened, but i'm no longer able to utilize my PCI wifi adapter. Thoughts? Thank you so much for any help or direction you can provide.

**Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**

**lshw -C network** results:

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:1c:a2:06:2d:99
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:fdec0000-fdedffff memory:fde00000-fde0ffff
```

**rfkill list** results:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

**Within settings**:

No wi-fi adapter found
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:1c:a2:06:2d:99
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:fdec0000-fdedffff memory:fde00000-fde0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: 40:8d:5c:74:2d:91
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.86.71 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fdcff000-fdcfffff memory:fdbfc000-fdbfffff
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory
```

**nmcli device show wlan0**

Note: I tried nmcli device show wlan0 | grep IP4.DNS and nothing displayed

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         68:1C:A2:06:2D:99
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

**sudo lshw -short -class network**

```
H/W path            Device      Class       Description
=======================================================
/0/100/5/0          wlan0       network     AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/6/0          eth0        network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabi
```

**lspci -k | grep -A**

```
grep: option requires an argument -- 'A'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

**-i "Network controller"**

```
-i: command not found
```

**ls -l /etc/resolv.conf**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 31  2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

**ls -al /etc/netplan**

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 21 13:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 158 root root 12288 Apr  4 22:42 ..
```

**sudo ifconfig wlan0 up**

Nothing display

Started to have this impact after an upgrade (I assume - didn't notice it right away, but did an upgrade not that long ago).

---

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pico /etc/netplan/config.yaml**
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo netplan --debug generate**

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:19312): DEBUG: 21:03:25.159: Processing input file /etc/netplan/config.yaml..
** (generate:19312): DEBUG: 21:03:25.159: starting new processing pass
** (generate:19312): DEBUG: 21:03:25.159: Generating output files..
```

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo netplan apply** 
**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:1c:a2:06:2d:99
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:fdec0000-fdedffff memory:fde00000-fde0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: 40:8d:5c:74:2d:91
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.86.71 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fdcff000-fdcfffff memory:fdbfc000-fdbfffff
```

---

***April 9th 9:13CT***

**lspci -k | grep -A 4 -i "Network controller"**

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

**rfkill unblock all**

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:1c:a2:06:2d:99
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:fdec0000-fdedffff memory:fde00000-fde0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: 40:8d:5c:74:2d:91
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.86.71 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fdcff000-fdcfffff memory:fdbfc000-fdbfffff
```

***April 11th 10:21 pm CT***

Re-seated wifi card and took the following screen shot:
[no wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjhMf.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema updated my post. Thanks so much for looking at it.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of the following commands: 1. `nmcli device show wlan0 | grep IP4.DNS` 2. `sudo lshw -short -class network` and 3 `lspci -k | grep -A 4 -i "Network controller"` and 5. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Curious that /etc/netplan didn't have any .yaml files. Try `ls -al /etc/netplan`. Was this an upgrade, or fresh install? Is airport mode enabled? Try `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`.

Comment: Updated original post with all requested commands. Noticed this shortly after an upgrade (but admit I didn't notice right away). 

I do not see an option for airport mode (desktop computer).  @heynnema

Comment: @Marmayogi I edited the orginal post with the requested commands. thanks for the help!

Comment: @deltapie give me a couple of minutes to put together an answer for you...

Comment: @deltapie Done. Do my answer. Report back.

Comment: @deltapie, please re-issue this command: `lspci -k | grep -A 4 -i "Network controller"` and post output.

Comment: @deltapie, please issue this command `rfkill unblock all` and **reboot**. Now check whether Wi-Fi enabled  or not by trying to connect to internet.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. New to the forum and didn't notice the reply (so very sorry). Did the above commands, rebooted, still no wireless card shown in UI settings menu.

Comment: @deltapie Did you ever get this problem resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - point release (18.04.3 LTS) of OS fixed issue.

Comment: Darn... I have the same problem on 18.04.4...

Answer (score 2):

In `terminal`...

`sudo pico /etc/netplan/config.yaml` # create/edit the file

Enter the following text using copy/paste...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Save the file. Exit the editor.

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`sudo lshw -C network` # check to see if wlan0 is NOT DISABLED

Copy/paste the output of the above three commands into your question so I can take a look.

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Check wireless operation using the standard NetworkManager GUI menu.

**Update #1:**

Re-seat the PCI wifi card.

Check to see if you have a function key to enable/disable wireless.

Check to make sure the airplane mode is off...

[image]

Comment: Posted the results in the original post. After reboot "no wi-fi adapter found. Make sure you have a wi-fi adapter plugged and turned on"

Comment: After reboot: sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface

Comment: @deltapie I'm a little confused. The last lshw command correctly shows wla0 as enabled. Are you saying that after the reboot it showed disabled again? Does `rfkill` still show no wireless?

Comment: Correct, after the reboot it showed disabled again. rfkill shows ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked (thank you again for helping!)

Comment: sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface

Comment: @deltapie Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: updated post with screenshot after removing wifi card and replacing back in computer. Still no luck.

Comment: update - downloaded WICD network manager and i'm able to connect to wifi. Very odd. Network Manager issue? Would like to get this working without using wicd.

Comment: Ok, lets look at syslog. Two different commands. They'll be lengthy, so post them to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the links. `grep -i wlan0 /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i NetworkManager /var/log/syslog*`. (this is a "*" at the end of syslog)

Comment: The first command returned zero results. The second command is pasted in the following location:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vtcrKGfDwt/

Comment: Try a different PCI slot please. Also, please show me `rfkill list`. Report back.

Comment: No other PCI slot. 

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: @deltapie  If `rfkill unblock wlan0` doesn't work, and wifi settings shows no wifi card, and there's no wifi disable switch or function key... I'd boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB... and if wifi works there... at this point, I'd backup my data and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @deltapie Please keep me posted, ok?

Answer (score 1):

If Wi-Fi mysteriously disappeared without trace after your laptop was been left for a little time while not charging, and shows the symptoms described in this question despite having correct, up-to-date drivers etc: check that Ubuntu hasn't just slyly disconnected the Wi-Fi adapter to save power.

Go to the "Power" section of settings and check the switch labelled *"**Wi-Fi** Turn off Wi-Fi to save power"* is turned **on**.

[image]

The labelling here is [potentially confusing](https://superuser.com/questions/1381066/i-want-to-turn-off-turn-off-wifi-to-save-power-and-turn-off-bluetooth-to-save). This is **a toggle for Wi-Fi itself**, and it might be automatically flipped off by the OS to save power. It does *not* control that "Turn off Wi-Fi to save power" feature.

- If this switch is **on**, Wi-Fi is on as normal
- If this switch is **off**, Wi-Fi is disabled completely and disappears from the places you might normally look to manage the Wi-Fi.

  - Wi-Fi settings displays nothing but "No wi-fi adapter found"
  - The top right system tray alternates between an "airplane mode" icon that does not restore wifi on disabling airplane mode, and simply not mentioning wifi as if this is a laptop with no wifi adapter,
  - `nmcli device status` lists no "wi-fi" device at all
- It appears that [there is no simple control to disable the feature of disabling Wi-Fi to save power](https://superuser.com/questions/1091367/ubuntu-16-04-cannot-prevent-wifi-sleep-during-screen-lock?rq=1) (if I find one I'll edit it in)

---

**Update**: this worked for me a couple of times, but just now I had the same problem of WiFi disappearing after suspend, but this time the WiFi option was even missing from the "Power" settings screen. Nothing in `ifconfig -a` (missing `wlo1` entry), or `rfkill list` (showed bluetooth only, missing `Wireless LAN` entry), or `sudo lshw -C network` (listed only Ethernet, missing `Wireless interface` entry).

The only thing that worked for me this latest time was restarting the laptop.

Comment: Also check any 3rd party energy saving software you might have - e.g. I seem to have had this problem less after disabling WiFi disabling options in power profiles in the "Slimbook Energy Preferences" applet